# Why is $n^2 \log^2 n+2n\log n+1$ big $O (n^2 \log^2 n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why is $n^2\log^2 n+2n\log n+1$ $O(n^2 \log^2 n)$?

Why is the $2n\log n$ ignored?

Comment: Because $2n \log n$ is *much* smaller than $n^2 \log^2 n$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: How do you it is smaller so quickly by inspection? Is it because n < n^2 or is it because log n is < log^2 n?

Comment: $n$ is much less than $n^2$, and $\log^2 n$ is bigger than $\log n$.

Comment: so the fact that 2nlogn is small allows it to be ignored?

Comment: Read the definition of Big Oh notation: Small terms can be rolled inside large terms by making the constant (usually denoted $C$) very slightly worse.

Comment: making the constant very slightly worse as in just ignore them because the impact is small?

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hopital's Rule,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/n}{1}=0\ .$$
Therefore
$$\log n=O(n)\ .$$
Hence $n\log n=O(n^2)$ and so $2n\log n=O(n^2\log^2n)$.

Comment: How come logn is O(n)? How come the log disappear in this case it is not a constant. How come nlogn is O(n^2)? I can't see the big o through quick inspection. May you show me a step by step of how you would arrive to that answer? How did 2nlogn become big O(n^2log^2n)?

Comment: See expanded answer.

Comment: It looks like you are dividing by n top and bottom. logn/n = 1/n?  n/n = 1 right? Still not sure why that would prove logn to be O(n). If nlogn = O(n^2) wouldn't 2nlogn be O(2n^2) instead of O(n^2log^2n)?

Comment: If you are not familiar with L'Hopital's Rule try watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8YDkl-nIJM).